# Kitchen light is causing virtually all other circuits to not work even though they aren’t tripped

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I had a fluorescent light fixture in my kitchen that stopped working. I tried replacing the bulbs and they would flicker slightly but never turn on. I decided to replace the fixture altogether with an LED light. I disconnected the old light and used the same wiring configuration for the LED light. The light works but now the majority of my other lights/outlets will not work throughout the house. It appears that any outlet/switch with wiring connected to one of the four GFCIs in my house does not work. None of these circuits are tripped and I have tried flipping the breakers multiple times.

I disconnected the new light but the GFCIs still would not operate.I unplugged all appliances and ran an extension cord from a working outlet to my refrigerator. Mysteriously a couple of hours later all of the previously non-working outlets turned on without flipping any breakers.

The next day I reconnected the new light and everything was working fine until I switched my refrigerator from the extension cord back to its outlet. As soon as I plugged it in all of the GFCI-connected outlets shut off again. I have disconnected the new light again but it’s been several hours and the GFCIs are still all dead.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this one light fixture has caused 80% of my switches/outlets across several circuits to malfunction?

Comment: Picture of your circuit breaker panel and picture of the wiring to the light may help.

Comment: Are all the GFCis on the same circuit?  Is there a fifth GFCI on that circuit also?  I'm wondering if somebody found that fifth GFCI tripped, and reset it, unbeknownst to you. Also when you installed the new light did you find any "spare" wires?

Comment: Either you went and disconnected  a primary power feed (or neutral), or something unrelated to the change in light fixture happened at the same time.

Comment: You should not cascade GFCI breakers or it will do funny things. It sounds like that is what happened to you.